# Como determinar o nível de acesso dos elementos de uma classe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento

Esta é uma questão do concurso da Secitec 2018 para o cargo de professor de informática. Entrei com recurso com relação a esta questão pelo fato de que não há qualificadores, mas sim modificadores de acesso tais como: private, protected e public. A palavra reservada "package" não é um modificador de acesso explícito segundo Deitel & Deitel. Qual alternativa, neste caso seria a correta? Segue à seguir a questão.

Encapsulamento é um dos princípios básicos
utilizados na programação orientada a objetos, que
possibilita restringir o acesso a variáveis e métodos de
uma classe. Para determinar o nível de acesso dos
elementos de uma classe são usados os qualificadores,
sendo que dois deles são caracterizados a seguir.

(I) É o nível mais rígido em que apenas os métodos da
própria classe têm acesso a variáveis e outros
métodos.

(II) É o nível em que as variáveis e métodos podem ser
acessados apenas por outras classes pertencentes
aos mesmo pacote.

Os qualificadores (I) e (II) são denominados,
respectivamente:

A) public e package

B) public e protected

C) private e package

D) private e protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependendo da interpretação da banca examinadora pode ser alternativa C ou pergunta anulada. De fato o termo package não se aplica ao modificador de acesso e sim ao nível de acesso (package-protected, ou protegido em nível de pacote). O fato de chamar modificador de qualificador está sujeito à interpretação da banca, pois é possível entender um pelo outro, embora o termo usual seja modificador.

Comment: A alternativa D não estaria correta? O modificador protected define, para o elemento (variável ou método), o acesso a nivel de pacote, correto?

Comment: Como foi usado o termo "apenas" na afirmação II, penso que está excluído o protected, pois uma subclasse em outro pacote não poderia acessar visto que seriam permitidas "apenas" classes do mesmo pacote. Já com o protected isso seria possível.

Comment: Correto. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil, você pode aceitá-la clicando no "v" no canto superior esquerdo da mesma, abaixo das setas de votação.